# Is Coping Git Root Folders and Adding them to Git Client on another system (with add existing projects button) enough and same as cloning them again?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, github-desktop

Ultimately I want to have my projects on another system and keep working from where i left off as usual (by coping folders not by reclonening them). My Git project were saved on cloud.

I copied my all these Git projects to another system. If I had add these projects using "Add existing projects on my system" button, will these projects become local offline projects? or will they be recognised as cloud projects as usual.

Comment: @JBallin Yes im using github desktop

Comment: Did you copy the hidden `.git` folders as well as the other contents?

Comment: @JimRedmond Yes they are present and populated

Comment: Ok. What do you mean by "local offline" vs. "cloud"?

Comment: @JBallin You know how we can create a new empty git project using "Create a new rep. on your hard drive" . they stay local

Comment: I don't use a GUI. Please explain in git CLI terms. I'm guessing that would just call `git init` in a new folder.

Comment: @JBallin Yes, probably. I keep my name and my mail all credentials the same will they be pushed to the cloud after the initialize.

Comment: Maybe you can clarify the current problem? Seems to me like you just want a cloud service to automatically sync 2 folders. Are you having an issue getting the GUI to pick up the synced project?

Comment: @JBallin this was therotical. i haven't add the projects on the new system yet. i will try now and post it about it